# Open a youtube link in a popup when clicking a div

Tags: javascript, php, html, onclick

I want the entire button (div) to open a youtube link in a pop-up. The pop-up is connected with the class 'popup-youtube'. The problem with this code is that the youtube link opens in youtube.com and not in the pop-up.

It's about this part:

```
        <div onclick="location.href='//www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo get_youtube_from_url( $hero_youtube_link_url_nl ) ?>';" style="cursor:pointer;" class="btn btn-secondary popup-youtube"><span href="//www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo get_youtube_from_url( $hero_youtube_link_url_nl ) ?>" onclick="$('#button-youtube-nl').click();"><?php echo esc_html( $hero_youtube_link_text ) ?></span>
```

The result of this code is opening the video in youtube, and not in the popup.

The following code actually works like I wanted:

```
<a id="button-youtube-nl" href="//www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo get_youtube_from_url( $hero_youtube_link_url_nl ) ?>"
```

But I'd like to make it work with the onclick="location.href" code. So if you click on the entire div you would get a pop-up with the video.

Below the fully code:

```
    <?php
$hero_youtube_link_text   = get_field( 'hero_youtube_link_text' );
$hero_youtube_link_url_nl = get_field( 'hero_youtube_link_url_nl' );
$hero_youtube_link_url_en = get_field( 'hero_youtube_link_url_en' );
$hero_youtube_link_url_de = get_field( 'hero_youtube_link_url_de' );
if ( $hero_youtube_link_text ) : ?>
    <div class="hero__video">
        <div onclick="location.href='//www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo get_youtube_from_url( $hero_youtube_link_url_nl ) ?>';" style="cursor:pointer;" class="btn btn-secondary popup-youtube"><span href="//www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo get_youtube_from_url( $hero_youtube_link_url_nl ) ?>" onclick="$('#button-youtube-nl').click();"><?php echo esc_html( $hero_youtube_link_text ) ?></span>
            <div class="flags">
                <a id="button-youtube-nl" href="//www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo get_youtube_from_url( $hero_youtube_link_url_nl ) ?>"
                   class="popup-youtube"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/flag-nl.png"/></a>
                <a href="//www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo get_youtube_from_url( $hero_youtube_link_url_de ) ?>"
                   class="popup-youtube"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/flag-de.png"/></a>
                <a href="//www.youtube.com/watch?v=<?php echo get_youtube_from_url( $hero_youtube_link_url_en ) ?>"
                   class="popup-youtube"><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/images/flag-en.png"/></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1.use a iframe inner DIV

2.when click DIV change the iframe src

Answer (score 0):

//Add It In Your Code

```
$(this).click(function() { window.location = href; });
```

here You Can Use Your Div Id Also

```
$("#DivId").click(function() { window.location = href; });
```

Comment: In Your html File Add This Code Between <script></script> Tag